# Strange behavior with read()

Tags: c, posix

I discovered the function `read()`, but I don't understand everything.
Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     main(void)
{
    char array[10];
    int  ret;

    printf("read : ");
    fflush(stdout);

    array[sizeof(array) - 1] = '\0';
    ret = read(STDIN_FILENO, array, sizeof(array) - 1);

    printf("array = %s\n", array);
    printf("characters read = %d\n", ret);

    //getchar();

    return (0);                 
}
```

Here is an example of the running program :

```
$> ./a.out
read : hi guys how are you
array = hi guys h
characters read = 9
$> ow are you
zsh: command not found: ow
$>
```

Why is it launching a shell command after the end of the program?
I noticed that if I uncomment the `getchar()` line, this strange behavior disappears. I'd like to understand what is going on, if someone has an idea :)

Comment: You only read 9 characters from input: "ow are you" is next. The behaviour disappears when `getchar();` is uncommented because it reads up the next newline.

Comment: getchar( );  will read the next character, which is 'o', right ? There is still others characters in the input buffer at the end, no ?

Comment: Sorry am on Windows console not Posix, where the `getchar` makes no difference because the input is cleared before returning to the command shell. So `ow are you` was never printed either.

Comment: The only correct way to NUL-terminate the string read by `read` is to use the return value of the `read`; first check that it is not negative and then `buf[ret] = '\0';`. NUL-terminating before the read (as you do) will result in garbage in the string if the `read` cannot provide the number of characters you requested.

Comment: Yep that's a good idea :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typed about 20 characters, but you only read 9 characters with `read()`. Everything after that was left in the terminal driver's input buffer. So when the shell called `read()` after the program exited, it got the rest of the line, and tried to execute it as a command.

To prevent this, you should keep reading until you get to the end of the line.

Comment: Okay, the streams functions (stdio.h) and read( ) are not the same at all ... because this behavior cannot happen with a stream function, right ? What is the difference between  read( )'s input buffer, and let's say, fgets( )'s input buffer ?

Comment: stdio has its own input buffer, which might be something like 1K or 4K. So it does something like `read(fileno(stdin), buffer, 1000);`. This is big enough to read the entire line.

Comment: Oh okay, so i suppose that if I enter a veryyy long string with fgets( ), longer than stdio's buffer, I will get the "strange behavior shell" again. Maybe there is a thing to prevent this behavior with stdio's function, but basically that's the idea

Comment: @gam: that's correct. You can make `stdin` unbuffered (see `setvbuf`). Or you can change the size of the buffer used for `stdin` (again, see `setvbuf`). But when the buffer is full, it's full and the library won't read ahead again until it needs to.

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `read` is reading in the first 9 characters of what you've type. Anything else will be left in the input buffer so that when you program exits, your shell will read it instead.

You should check the return value of `read` so you know how much has been read as it's not guaranteed that it'll be the amount you ask for and also the value returned is used to indicate an error.

The string read in won't be null-terminated either, so you also should use the return value (if positive) to put the NUL character in so that your string is valid.

If you want to read in the whole line, you'll need to put in a loop and identify when there is an end of line character (most likely `'\n'`).